# How to solve Geoserver editing in QGIS returning read only error?

Tags: qgis, postgis, geoserver, wfs

After creating a table in Postgis, making it available in Geoserver and then creating the necessary stores and layers, I loaded the resulting WFS file in QGIS.

When trying to populate the features with an edit, I get faced with the following error:

> Could not commit changes to layer teststore:test
>
> Errors: ERROR: 1 feature(s) not added.
>        Provider errors:
>         WFS service exception:
>             {http://geoserver.org/teststore}test is read-only

I have admin privileges in Geoserver and Postgres, and I haven't found anything resembling a read only restriction.

How to get around this problem?

Comment: You should read up on WFS-T.

Comment: @Vesanto care to elaborate?

Comment: It's hard to tell from your question what you have tried in GeoServer, and I no expert on the matter. But WFS does not support editing. For editing you will need WFS-T, which is transactional WFS.

Comment: @Vesanto Like I've said, I simply tried adding the Geoserver layer as a WFS but when I tried editing, it did not work saying it was read only. I don't see any option to make it a WFS-T and my internet search didn't produce any result

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem was solved by enabling jsonp in the geoserver

Comment: How are these thing related?  Why would you need to enable jsonp to do a WFS insert?

Answer (score 1):

The typical reason for this errors is that the underlying table does not have a primary key, it's a view in the database, or the layer is configured as "sql view" in GeoSever

Comment: It had a primary key, the problem was SQL view but now I'm not sure how I did it but it got fixed and now I'm able to fix my edits